# DVD burning program for creating menus, etc for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, dvd, dvd-burning

What's a good DVD burning program that lets you create menus and stuff? I like the one that comes with Windows but it can't `.mkv` files.

Comment: What OS? Windows only?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: sorry for my answer, had a facepalm moment realizing DVD burning, not encoding or converting. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/) is a force to be reckoned with.